# Scrapy: how to disable or change log?

Tags: python, scrapy

I've followed the [official tutoral of Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), it's wonderful!

I'd like to remove all of DEBUG messages from console output. Is there a way?

```
2013-06-08 14:51:48+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6029
2013-06-08 14:51:48+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6086
```

The doc told about to set a LOG_LEVEL, but ... in which file ?

Replying, please make referring to this directory structure. It's the mine. 
Plus, I've a 'test.py' in spyder folder

```
tutorial/
    scrapy.cfg
    tutorial/
        __init__.py
        items.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
        spiders/
            __init__.py
            ...
```

Where. in which file, and HOW must i set the log_level ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `settings.py` document:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

See [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-level).

Comment: thanks ! I read the link, but I was not founding where the doc explain in which file to the settings !

Comment: @realtebo file: `tutorial/tutorial/settings.py`

Comment: But it still shows information about scrappy, I want only to output logs what I specifically output in a code.

Comment: So change 'INFO' to 'WARNING', 'ERROR', or 'CRITICAL'

Answer (score 28):

You can also disable it completely with `LOG_ENABLED=False`. And you can pass settings when invoking the command: `scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_ENABLED=False`

Comment: Does case really matter for the `FALSE/False` values?

Comment: I use the above command and get the result: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'FALSE'". I try to replace "FALSE" with "0" and no error again now.

Comment: @Wolf it seems False will be parsed as boolean, FALSE will be parsed as string :/

Answer (score 12):

You can also use **--nolog** in command prompt.

**`> scrapy crawl myspider --nolog`**

--nolog command Sets **LOG_ENABLED** to **False**

see documentation [scrapy command line options](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#command-line-options)